# SQL Alchemy. has many relation that returns a particular column

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following tables:

```
Campaigns
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type                                                              | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                         | int(11) unsigned                                                  | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| campaign_type_id           | int(11)                                                           
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

CampaignsSiteList
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| campaign_id  | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| site_list_id | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm using SQL Alchemy and I want to create a relationship so that objects of class Campaign have an attribute that return the list of site_list_id associated with them. I don't want the relation to return the list of CampaignSiteList objects, but a list that contains the column site_list_id of CampaignsSiteList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a property on the class and pull them out yourself, something like:

```
class Campaigns():

   # column definitions here

   sites = relationship("CampaignSiteList", lazy="joined")

   @property
   def site_ids(self):
       return [d.id for d in self.sites]
```

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it would depend on if the relationship is lazy joined or deferred. In the case above, yeah that would probably work. If it were deferred, I'd imagine it would throw an error?

Comment: Isn't there a way like in ActiveRecord where you can choose which columns that relationship is going to return ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You can "defer" loading particular columns on the objects though. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#deferred-column-loading